# Como eu considero só o que seja número do que um usuário digitar em um input? (python)

Tags: python, string, int

```py
rabanada = int(input("Quantos quilos você pesa? "))

if rabanada > 100000:
   print("Você é gordo")

else:
   print("Você tá magro, rlx")
```

Se o usuário digitar: "100 quilos", como eu faço para o programa considerar só o número (100) e não a string (quilos) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai usar expressões regulares para isso. Algo como:

```py
import re

texto = '100 quilogramas'
peso = int(re.sub('\D', '', texto))
print(peso) # 100
```

O que o exemplo cima faz é pegar a string e remover tudo que não é número, para isso utiliza a expressão regular `\D`. No seu exemplo você faria algo como:

```py
import re

rabanada = int( re.sub('\D', '', input("Quantos quilos você pesa? ")) )

if rabanada > 100000:
   print("Você é gordo")

else:
   print("Você tá magro, rlx")
```

Só tem que ficar esperto que se não for digitado um número na entrada de dados um `ValueError` vai ser lançado porque ele vai tirar tudo que não for número, então no fim vai ficar algo como sendo `int('')`.

E vai lançar esse erro. Pode já validar antes, fazer a substituição e ver se tem caracteres ou faz um `try/except`.

Comment: Vale lembrar que se for digitado algo como `a1 b2 c3`, será considerado um peso igual a 123. Claro que não foi especificado um formato (aparentemente pode ser "qualquer coisa"), mas de qq forma, fica a dica :-)